# Category Axis Interaction

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following implementation.

http://jsfiddle.net/ao617j2j/

I would like to know when a user clicks on the categoryAxis label, it should hide/unhide corresponding bar stack.

```
categoryAxis: {
  categories: ["First Stock", "Second Stock", "Third Stock", "Fourth Stock", "Fifth Stock"],
},
```

Comment: Have a look at the axisLabelClick event handler: http://jsfiddle.net/ao617j2j/1/

Comment: I have given points on your other questions for this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `axisLabelClick` event in this case, and get series data with relevant index and set the value to 0 and `redraw` it. I create a snippet code to hide the bar, to show the bar again I think you already got the idea. Good Luck! :D

```
axisLabelClick: function(e) {
    var series = e.sender.options.series;

    $.each(series, function(i, item){
      item.data[e.index] = 0;
    });
    e.sender.redraw();
}
```

Comment: setting the value to null instead of zero will make the chart leave a gap: http://jsfiddle.net/ao617j2j/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot Dion and Ezanker.

Comment: I have started learning kendo recently. I have been looking questions on SOF. I would like to know the following question if you have any idea. Thanks alot in advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377141/changing-the-start-point-in-stack-bar-chart