# Changing the Start point in Stack Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have came across the following implementation.

http://jsfiddle.net/ao617j2j/1/

As a default stack bar chart starts from 0, however, what if I want to start from +200. Is it possible?

```
 categoryAxis: {
     categories: ["First Stock", "Second Stock", "Third Stock", "Fourth Stock", "Fifth Stock"],
     axisCrossingValues: [0, 0, 10, 10],
 },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried to change the `valueAxes.min` value?

```
valueAxes: [{
    title: {
        text: "Dollar($)"
    },
    reverse: true,
    min: 200, // Changed this from 0 to 200
    max: 1600
}],
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ao617j2j/4/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, I would like to see all of them starts with 0, but my first stock does not have any data between 0-200. and it should show data after 200. I hope I have made it clear. I have upvoted your current answer.

Comment: @AndreaBanderas you mean, like the first stack should start from its initial value and no from the top of the chart area?

Comment: I mean assume there is no data for the first stock value until 200. But other have. First stock bar, between 0-200 no data, but after that data will be populated. Others have data starts from 0.

Comment: Your current solution shows all data starts from 200. But I have data for other stocks (second, third,fourth), except first stock.

Comment: Yes, exactly in your image

Comment: @AndreaBanderas I need to research but I'm afraid that can't be done, unfortunatelly.

Comment: Any idea for the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675620/remove-legend-color-boundary